# SQL for create own column and rows of the month

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table ORDER and i want to create each month revenue , is it possible ?

my query like this to just show one month

```
SELECT SUM(price) as revenue from order 
WHERE DATE(date_created) BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-31'
```

but i am not sure if sql allow to create table like this

```
month || start date  || end-date || revenue
 jan     2019-01-01    2019-01-31     $90
```

my table structure Order has columns : `client_name, total_price, date_modified , date_created,`

Comment: i advice you to read about [keywords/reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) and [Schema Object Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html) which more or less the naming convention MySQL supports..

Comment: Hi, can you share the table structure and sample data.

Comment: Read about `Group By`

Comment: Can you please share your table structure. Is there any date column?

Comment: @RamaSh just did

Comment: check my update :) @AnkitBajpai

Comment: Hi, Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Are you certain there will always be an order for the month(s) being queried or is that an unsafe assumption (and how should the output look if that is the case)

Comment: What are  `start date` and `end-date` supposed to represent? Simply the first and last day inn the month? Or the first and last day of the month where orders were placed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just group by MONTH of date_created after fetching the first and last day of the month-

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(date_created) MONTH
      ,DATE_ADD(date_created, interval -DAY(date_created)+ 1 DAY) start_date
      ,LAST_DAY(date_created) end_day
      ,SUM(price) revenue
FROM order
WHERE MONTH(date_created) BETWEEN MONTH(NOW()) -2 AND MONTH(NOW())
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(date_created)
        ,DATE_ADD(date_created, interval -DAY(date_created)+ 1 DAY)
        ,LAST_DAY(date_created)
```

Comment: how about if i want to just show like current month , and the last 2 month of current month ? what shouldni change from above query

Comment: This looks like an oracle answer to a mysql question (to_char,last_day).

Comment: @P.Salmon, Converted to MySQL.

Comment: @Sder, Please try now.

Comment: anyway , iit say i need to convert to date , so get error ,

Comment: @Sder, Can you please try now.

Comment: the month colum all current_mont now and it only sum current month for all

Comment: Now I think you must either create a fiddle with sample data or post the sample data and expected result here.

Answer (score 1):

May be this can help

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(date_created) AS month,
    DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(date_created),interval 1 DAY),interval -1 MONTH) AS start_date,
    LAST_DAY(date_created) AS end_date,
    concat("$ ",sum(total_price)) AS revenue 
FROM `orders` 
group by DATE_FORMAT(date_created,'%Y-%m')
```

You can change the month name in short form by using

```
DATE_FORMAT(date_created, '%b') AS month
```

Note: Please try to change the name of table because it's a MySQL's reserved keyword.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you can use `LAST_DAY` in order to always get the same day for any day in a month. Group by this, then use date functions on this to get the month's first day and the month's name.

```
select
  date_format(last_day(date_created), '%M %Y') as month,
  last_day(date_created) + interval 1 day - interval 1 month as start_date,
  last_day(date_created) as end_date,
  sum(total_price) as revenue
from mytable
group by last_day(date_created)
order by last_day(date_created);
```

If start_date and end_date shall refer to the first and last placed order in the month (i.e. not just the month's first and last day), then replace the lines with

```
min(date_created) as start_date,
max(date_created) as end_date,
```